# How to implement addition to all submatrix elements?

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to implement matrix class for simple operations with plain python (no numpy and etc.).

Here is part of it:

```
class Matrix(list):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return list.__getitem__(self, item)
        except TypeError:
            rows, cols = item
            return [row[cols] for row in self[rows]]
```

It allows to do things like this:

```
m = Matrix([[i+j for j in [0,1,2,3]] for i in [0,4,8,12]])
print(m[0:2, 0:2])
will print: [[0, 1], [4, 5]]
```

I also want to be able to add/multiply all submatrix elements by given value, like:

```
m[0:2, 0:2] += 1
print(m[0:2, 0:2])
should print: [[1, 2], [5, 6]]
```

It's not clear which magic methods should I implement to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

First, inheriting from `list` is a bad move here. A matrix doesn't support the kinds of operations a list does; for example, you can't `append` to or `extend` a matrix, and item assignment is completely different. Your matrix should contain a list, not be a list.

As for what magic methods you need, `m[0:2, 0:2] += 1` roughly translates to the following:

```
temp = m.__getitem__((slice(0, 2), slice(0, 2)))
temp = operator.iadd(temp, 1)
m.__setitem__((slice(0, 2), slice(0, 2)), temp)
```

where `operator.iadd` tries `temp.__iadd__`, `temp.__add__`, and `(1).__radd__` to perform the addition.

You need to implement `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to retrieve the submatrix and assign the new submatrix. Additionally, `__getitem__` will need to return a matrix, rather than a list.

You should probably implement both `__add__` and `__iadd__`; while `__add__` alone would be sufficient for this case, `__iadd__` will be necessary for operations like `m += 1` to work in-place instead of replacing `m` with a new matrix object.

Comment: Well, maybe you can share some code. Because for everything what I'm trying I got `TypeError` even before it goes to magic methods

Answer (score 0):

**NO**. `__iadd__` will do the trick for you if the magic was:

```
m += 2
```

But the magic is executed over `m[0:2, 0:2]`. You need to ensure that when slicing your matrix you get a different object, and not a list of lists, since list of lists do not support `__iadd__`.