# How to implement interface for submatrix like m[1:3, 0:2] += 1?

Tags: python, matrix

I already asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421545/how-to-implement-addition-to-all-submatrix-elements) but still can't figure out how to implement this.

I have matrix class:

```
class Matrix(list):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return list.__getitem__(self, item)
        except TypeError:
            rows, cols = item
            return [row[cols] for row in self[rows]]
```

It allows to do things like this:

```
m = Matrix([[i+j for j in [0,1,2,3]] for i in [0,4,8,12]])
print(m[0:2, 0:2])
will print: [[0, 1], [4, 5]]
```

I also want to be able to add/multiply all submatrix elements by given value, like:

```
m[0:2, 0:2] += 1
print(m[0:2, 0:2])
should print: [[1, 2], [5, 6]]
```

I'm trying to implement those methods: `__add__`, `__setitem__`

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    print(key, value)

def __add__(self, item):
    print(item)
    for i in range(self):
        for j in range(self[0]):
            self[i][j] += item
```

At least I want to see they print something. But it doesn't happen. I'm trying with such example:

```
m[1:2, 2:3] = m[1:2, 2:3] + 1
```

And get an error like: `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`.

So, I'm not even at magic methods. Call fails before. How to do this?

Comment: Why are you reinventing numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return Matrix object from "**getitem**"

```
class Matrix(list):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print "get"
        try:
            return Matrix(list.__getitem__(self, item))
        except TypeError:
            rows, cols = item
            return Matrix([row[cols] for row in self[rows]])
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(key, value)

    def __add__(self, item):
        print "messi the great"
        print(item)
        # for i in range(self):
        #     for j in range(self[0]):
        #         self[i][j] += item
m = Matrix([[i+j for j in [0,1,2,3]] for i in [0,4,8,12]])
print m[1:2, 2:3]
m[1:2, 2:3] = m[1:2, 2:3] + 1
```